# my data are not inserting in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with my data they're not inserting into the database even though There is no error showed in my code
here is the insertion code

```
    <?php
$objPdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bea','root','');

if(isset($_POST['suiv']) && isset($_FILES['actenaisss']) && isset($_FILES['piec']) && isset($_FILES['resid'])){
       
       include "config.php";

       echo "<pre>";
       print_r($_FILES['actenaisss']);
       print_r($_FILES['piec']);
       print_r($_FILES['resid']);
       echo "</pre>";

       $img_name = $_FILES['actenaisss']['name'];
       $img_size = $_FILES['actenaisss']['size'];
       $tmp_name = $_FILES['actenaisss']['tmp_name']; 
       $error = $_FILES['actenaisss']['error'];

       $img_name1 = $_FILES['piec']['name'];
       $img_size1 = $_FILES['piec']['size'];
       $tmp_name1 = $_FILES['piec']['tmp_name'];
       $error1 = $_FILES['piec']['error'];

       $img_name2 = $_FILES['resid']['name'];
       $img_size2 = $_FILES['resid']['size'];
       $tmp_name2 = $_FILES['resid']['tmp_name'];
       $error2 = $_FILES['resid']['error'];
      

      /* $numps = $_POST['numps'];
       $numan = $_POST['numan'];
       $typep = $_POST['typep'];*/

      if ($error === 0 && $error1 === 0 && $error2 === 0) {
          if ($img_size > 125000 && $img_size1 > 125000 && $img_size2 >125000) {
            $em = "Sorry, your file is too large !";
           header("Location: form-merci.php?error=$em");
          }else{
            $img_ex = pathinfo($img_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $img_ex1 = pathinfo($img_name1, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $img_ex2 = pathinfo($img_name2, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 

            $img_ex_lc = strtolower($img_ex);
            $img_ex_lc1 = strtolower($img_ex1);
            $img_ex_lc2 = strtolower($img_ex2);

            $allowed_exs = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "JPG", "JPEG", "PNG", "PDF", "pdf", "txt", "TXT");

            if (in_array($img_ex_lc, $allowed_exs) && in_array($img_ex_lc1, $allowed_exs) && in_array($img_ex_lc2, $allowed_exs)) {
                
                $new_img_name = uniqid("IMG-", true).'.'.$img_ex_lc;
                $new_img_name1 = uniqid("IMG-", true).'.'.$img_ex_lc1;
                $new_img_name2 = uniqid("IMG-", true).'.'.$img_ex_lc2;

                $img_upload_path = 'files/'.$new_img_name;
                $img_upload_path1 = 'files/'.$new_img_name1;
                $img_upload_path2 = 'files/'.$new_img_name2;

                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $img_upload_path);
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name1, $img_upload_path1);
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name2, $img_upload_path2);



$pdoStat = $objPdo->prepare('INSERT INTO formulaire_depot VALUES(NULL, :nom, :prenom, :nais, :lnais, :pprenom, :mnom, :mprenom, :actenais, :typepie, :numpi, :datedeliv, :delivpar, :prof, :numero, :email, :actenaisss, :piec, :resid)');

$pdoStat->bindValue(':nom', $_POST['nom'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStat->bindValue(':prenom', $_POST['prenom'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStat->bindValue(':nais', $_POST['nais'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStat->bindValue(':lnais', $_POST['lnais'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStat->bindValue(':pprenom', $_POST['pprenom'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStat->bindValue(':mnom', $_POST['mnom'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStat->bindValue(':mprenom', $_POST['mprenom'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStat->bindValue(':actenais', $_POST['actenais'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStat->bindValue(':typepie', $_POST['typepie'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStat->bindValue(':numpi', $_POST['numpi'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStat->bindValue(':datedeliv', $_POST['datedeliv'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStat->bindValue(':delivpar', $_POST['delivpar'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStat->bindValue(':prof', $_POST['prof'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStat->bindValue(':numero', $_POST['numero'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStat->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStat->bindValue(':actenaisss', $new_img_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStat->bindValue(':piec', $new_img_name1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStat->bindValue(':resid', $new_img_name2, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$insert = $pdoStat->execute();

                if ($insert) {
                     header("Location: form-merci.php");
                }

            }else{
                $em = "You can't upload this type of file!";
                header("Location: form-merci.php?error=$em");
            }
          }
      }else{
           $em = "unknown error occurred!";
           header("Location: form-merci.php?error=$em");
      }
  }else{
    header("Location: form-merci.php");
  }
?>
```

It was working perfectly before adding the files inputs and when I added the files when I click on the submit button it takes me to the "form-merci.php" which means that the data are inserting successfuly but when I go the the table in phpmyadmin I don't find the data insert
Please help me with this I really need it Thank you !!

Comment: *"it takes me to the "form-merci.php" which means that the data are inserting successfuly"* - Or it means that the very first `if` condition was `false`.  How have you confirmed which is happening?

Comment: Actually, I don't know what is happenning as I said in the post they were adding to the phpmyadmin before adding the files inputs

Comment: The first thing you'll want to do is find out what specifically is happening in the code.  In the absense of actual debugging, in this particular case one thing you can do is add unique values to your `form-merci-php` URLs (like your error messages in some of the `else` blocks) to observe which condition is actually happening.

Comment: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "header" in C:\xampp\htdocs\BEA\insertion2.php on line 90"  That's what's what happened when I added unique values to the form-merci.php

Comment: Then you have a syntax error on or before line 90.  At the very least, now that you've started reading error logs/messages, the system is telling you about the problem.  You can now start to address that specific problem.  Good luck!